# Removing Kth node from end of Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

Everything is working except for when I want to remove the first node in the list `if (kthToLast == 0) head = head.next;`. I do not know why it does not remove the first element since `head = head.next;` should work.

Thanks.

```
// 2.2 Implement an algorithm to find the kth to last element of a singly linked list.

public class RemoveKthToLast {

    static Node head;
    static int count = 0;

    public static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
            count++;
        }
    }

    public Node removeKthToLast(Node head, int n) {
        if (head == null || n < 1)
            System.out.println("invalid");;

        int count = 0;
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) { // count number of nodes in list
            temp = temp.next;
            count++;
        }

        if (n > count)
            System.out.println("n is greater than length of list");;

        int kthToLast = count - n;

        // remove first node 
        if(kthToLast == 0) 
             head = head.next;

        for (int i = 0; i < kthToLast - 1; i++) 
            head = head.next;

        head.next = head.next.next;
        return head;
    }

    // prints out contents of linked-list
    public void toString(Node node) {
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            node = node.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        RemoveKthToLast list = new RemoveKthToLast();

        list.head = new Node(1);
        list.head.next = new Node(2);
        list.head.next.next = new Node(3);
        list.head.next.next.next = new Node(4);

        list.removeKthToLast(head, 0);
        list.toString(head);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that even when you're trying to delete the first node in the linked list, you still proceed with the rest of the method, which should only be executed when trying to remove nodes other than the first node. For example, let's say you're trying to remove the head. Yes, the head field gets updated to the 2nd node in the list. However, the method doesn't end there and executes the line `head.next = head.next.next` which will incorrectly delete the 3rd node in the linked list. Therefore, the solution is to basically end the method once the head field is reset.

```
public Node removeKthToLast(Node head, int n) {
    if (head == null || n < 1)
        System.out.println("invalid");;

    int count = 0;
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null) { // count number of nodes in list
        temp = temp.next;
        count++;
    }

    if (n > count)
        System.out.println("n is greater than length of list");;

    int kthToLast = count - n;

    // remove first node 
    if(kthToLast == 0){
         head = head.next;
         return head;//end the method here when removing the 1st node
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < kthToLast - 1; i++) 
        head = head.next;

    head.next = head.next.next;
    return head;
    }
```

Also, make sure to update your list's head node in the main.

```
list.head = list.removeKthToLast(head,4);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, returning head does not seem to work.

Comment: May I ask what is the result when you are trying to remove the first node?

Comment: For example if the linked list is 1->2->3->4 (length of 4), and I want to remove the 4th node from the end of the list (so n=4), then the resulting node should be 2->3->4 since node 1 is the 4th from the end of the list. Hope that helps!

Comment: I understand but what is the output you are currently getting that is incorrect? Also, I could see some potential errors in your for loop because you are updating the front in the efforts to delete the kth to last node, which could delete all the nodes before the (kth - 1) to last node.

Comment: so when k = 4, the output is still 1->2->3->4 instead of 2->3->4. So weird. Oh I ran the code and the for-loop seems like its fine. Thanks for mentioning it though.

Comment: Okay, I believe it could be because in the main, you are not resetting the list's head, see my edit.

Comment: That seemed to have worked. Thanks so much for your help :-) !!

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is that the first node isn't removed then try this

```
// remove first node 
if(kthToLast == 0) {
     head = head.next;
     return head;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately returning the head doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: you could use a recursive function here and your code will be astoundly simple:

```
public Node removeKthFromLast(Node head, int k) {
    int n;
    Node p = head;
    for (n=0;head != null;n++) {
      p = head.next;
    }
    return removeKthFromLastAux(head, n-k);
}

private Node removeKthFromLastAux(Node head, int ik) {
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (ik == 0) {
        return head.next;
    }
    head.next = removeKthFromLastAux(head, ik-1);
    return head;
}
```